# Font not showing on Windows (taking space)

Tags: fonts

(Complete font newbie here)
I took a stock font and created a certain glyph which was the combination of other glyphs

The steps involved were:

- Open in fontforge, and then save the font as dir.
- Use http://sourceforge.net/p/unifraktur/code/HEAD/tree/unifraktur-maguntia/trunk/manipulation.py (code in German). method `ersetzen_durch_Kompositglyph` in the said python script can combine two glyphs into one. I created a long word after tacking one char onto other. 
  I then delete everything but A-Za-z, and all the temporary chars involved in the process.
- Then generate font using Fontforge by opening the dir into it. I generate ttf, woff, svg versions, and convert ttf to eot using an online converter. 
  More here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48695/make-a-character-in-a-font-look-like-multiple-characters-of-the-same-font

I then embedded the font in my webpage. The problem I'm facing is that while my webpage display fine on some browser + OS combinations and not on others. Here's the combination: Linux = Ubuntu 13.04

- Displays perfectly: 
  Win10 + IE, Linux + Firefox, Linux + Chrome, Linux+PhantomJS
- Doesn't display the long glyph but shows empty space that long.
  Win10 + Firefox, Win10 + Chrome, Win7+Firefox, Win7+IE
- Displays space 1 glyph long
  Win7+Chrome, Win10+PhantomJS

Would anyone know why this is happening, and if there is a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script generates composite glyphs by referencing (linking) to the component glyphs. So if you combine [A] and [B] to [AB] and [AB] and [C] to [ABC], the latter will not be a standalone glyph. For example, if you make changes to [A], [AB] and [ABC] will also change.

Therefore deleting the intermediate glyphs ([AB] in the example) will cause problems and it’s surprising rather suprising that it did work on some platforms.

Comment: Also, if you have questions on that script, please ask me first, as I am very likely to be able to answer them in no time. You probably wasted more moderator’s time with this question than mine.